# Re-use value in piped command line

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, command-line-interface

Is there a way to set a variable and then re-use it throughout a piped bash command, e.g.

```
> set v <VALUE> | comm1 v | comm2 v
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you expect to flow through the first pipe but I guess the following solves your problem anyway. Asuming you use `bash`:

```
v=<VALUE>; comm1 $v | comm2 $v
```

Note that around `=` no spaces are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The way you seem to have described the problem, no. If you assign a value just before a command, that value gets exported to the command's environment, but doesn't affect the current (shell's) environment.

```
$ echo $x

$ x=123 bash -c 'echo $x'
123
$ echo $x

$
```

When you use a pipe you're creating subshells of the current shell, so only names assigned in the current shell and subsequent subshells will be recognized.

```
$ a=123; echo wat | echo $a
123
$ #                 ^ subshell ^
```

Of course, it's easy to do this if you just do the assignments as a separate step, as in…

```
a=123; foo | ( b=123; bar ) | baz …
```

but you need to manually wrap the subshell so the assignment becomes part of each pipe chunk.

Alternatively you can just create full shells as children:

```
a=123 bash -c 'echo $a | bar | baz'
```

But I can't think of any way in which that's a better approach than just assigning values when you need them.